# OpenGl ES on iOS lightshading removes color

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am still getting used to OpenGL with shaders, been using OGL ES 1.0 before but it's time to update my knowledge! Now I have a problem with the simple shaders I'm looking at and I have searched for 2 days straight with no luck of a solution.
Problem is this: I render some cubes with a VBO in the form of (Vx, Vy, Vz, NormalX, NormalY, NormalZ, ColorR, ColorG, ColorB, ColorA) and this works nicely when I render it without the shader but I have to use the shader for translation and stuff (I know it can be done without but bear with me). Here is my vertex shader, default from OGL template in XCode:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
uniform vec3 translation;
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec3 eyeNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 10.0);
    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(0.4, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0);

    float nDotVP = max(0.0, dot(eyeNormal, normalize(lightPosition)));

    colorVarying = diffuseColor * nDotVP;

    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * (position + vec4(translation, 1));
}
```

And the fragment shader, also default:

```
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = colorVarying;
}
```

Now this ALWAYS renders whatever triangles I draw in the same color (defined by diffuseColor) without regard for the colors in the VBO. So I have tried and failed with other fragment shader like `gl_FragColor = gl_FrontColor;` but gl_FrontColor/gl_Color etc aren't included in OpenGL ES and are deprecated in OpenGL 3.x or something. I have also viewed code using texture samplers but since I'm not using textures but colors it  gets a bit complicated for a beginner.

So my question is this, how would I have my fragmentshader find the Material Color of the current fragment being shaded?
If I should pass the colors in an array to the shaders, how would I do that and how, then, would I reference it with regard to the currently shading fragment?

(Some 'also's; tried not using a fragment shader but OGL doesn't allow only using vertex shader. Tried simply removing the gl_FragColor = colorVarying; but that leaves the colors really screwed up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a colour attribute to your shader:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec4 colour;
```

...and use that attribute instead of `diffuseColor`.

You must also tell OpenGL where to find that vertex attribute within your VBO using `glVertexAttribPointer` (I assume you are doing this for the position and normal attributes already).

Comment: Yep I just had to add
glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribColor, "color");
and
attribute vec4 color;
int the vertex shader
And that worked like a charm. Thank you very much!